# $.(ajax) in Firefox doesn't send RADIO from input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have thise code in my form (action="index.php" method="post" id="reform"):

```
   <input class="radio-input" id="reg_title1" type="radio" name="title" value="Mr." checked="checked">
   <input class="radio-input" id="reg_title2" type="radio" name="title" value="Mrs.">
```

When passing this through:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'reg.php',
                    data: $("#regform").serialize(),
                    success: function (response) {
                        if(response == 'success') {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                        else {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
```

In Safari I get the "title" value. In Firefox it mysteriously is not posted! I made var_dump($_POST); and it shows the title value in the array in Safari, but not in Firefox. What is wrong with sending radio content?

Comment: Have you tried to take another name like `title` for your field? Reserved names (`title`Tag) are always causing prob's

Comment: Yes, I actually tried the German version "anrede" but wanted to make it more understandable so I translated it for Stackoverflow.

Comment: ok, is the field within the `form` tag and is it actually checked? Once none of the boxes are checked, the field is missing from th POST data by design.

Comment: Its checked by JavaScript... But I now made a work around with placing the value of the checked radio in an hidden input... So strange.

Comment: show the code which "checks" the box, probaly it is left "unchecked" for the form afterwards

Comment: I've tested this in FF 23, and it does send title variable.

Comment: @Dexa probably something wrong with the code which "checks" programatically.

Comment: In your text you said id of the form is "**reform**", but in ajax it's written "**regform**". Is it just a typo in SO post?